# What is the difference between "terrorist attack" and "terror attack"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Are "terrorist attack" and "terror attack" two distinct terms? Or do they both refer to the same thing (an attack committed by terrorists)? The two seem to be used interchangeably. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would be willing to argue that there _should_ be a difference, with "terror attack" being an attack perpetrated with the goal or effect of sowing fear, terror, etc., and "terrorist attack" is a terror attack perpetrated by a known terrorist group; but I haven't found any sources to back me in that distinction.

Comment: Technically, "terror attack" might be used to mean "anxiety attack".  But such use should probably be avoided since it leads to confusion.

Comment: *Terror attack* stops just short of labeling the perpetrators terrorists. This might be useful in cases of state terrorism or state-sponsored terrorism. States are commonly excluded from being terrorists by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Today the terms "terror attack" and "terrorist attack" seem to be used virtually interchangeably, with essentially the same meaning—an attack on civilians or on government personnel that aims to make the entire population fearful, suspicious, and pessimistic about their own safety and about the competence of their would-be protectors. The terms have had quite different histories, however.

---

***'Terror attack' in the news***

A very early instance of "terror attack" appears in Pierre Janet, [*The Mental State of Hystericals: A Study of Mental Stigmata and Mental Accidents*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AFFfxh-qKKAC&pg=PA394&dq=%22terror+attack%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizifuR9s_bAhUSPH0KHXPfAOcQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22terror%20attack%22&f=false) (1901):

> Another example: Dum. was frightened one evening on seeing a man, lying in a ditch, suddenly rise up before her. A very simple **terror attack**, which repeats itself regularly. Later on she is struck on seeing a patient attacked by a strange chorea and begins imitating her.

Evidently this "terror attack" refers to something similar to a panic attack.

The earliest relevant matches that an Elephind search for "terror attack" produces involve the peculiar compressed formulations of newspaper headlines. The first two of these are from the same newspaper. "[Start **Terror Attack** on Hun](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87093407/1918-07-08/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *Seattle [Washington] Star* [July 8, 1918), involves the assassination of the German ambassador in Moscow two days earlier; the reporter specifically contrasts "the terror of the German sword" with "the terror of the Russian bomb." (Russia had withdrawn from the ongoing First World War and was not at war with Germany when the incident occurred.)

Four years later, "[Launch **Terror Attack**: Moonshine Bandits Defy Government; Armed Men Raid Towns](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn87093407/1922-07-25/ed-1/seq-1/#words=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *Seattle [Washington] Star* (July 25, 1922), introduces a story about 25 moonshiners marauding through a Minnesota town, burning a leading citizen's lumber camps, dynamiting his hotel, and "intimidating his daughters."

Then comes this headline from the [*Madera [California] Tribune*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=MT19230130.2.6&txq=%2522terror+attack%2522) (January 30, 1923):

> Dublin Held Terror Grip by Bombings: Sniping, Bombing, and Arson Hold City in Turmoil: State Officers Are Fired Upon: Public Buildings And Homes Suffered in **Terror Attack**

The first main-text instances of "terror attack," however, are from the early days of the Second World War and refer to attacks by the regular military forces (especially air forces) of sovereign states on the civilian populations of enemy states for the specific purpose of inculcating terror in those populations.

The first of these is in a cross reference (which has something of the clipped style of a headline) in a [photo caption](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/98622777?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22) in the *[Lismore, New South Wales] Northern Star* (June 10, 1940):

> Like an ant-hill: One of the conical German air raid shelters, a type erected in Berlin, which has been bombed for the first time in history. (Story of Nazi air **terror attack** on U.K.— Page 5, cols. 1 and 2.)

The actual story on page 5 refers to the attack as a "Terror Raid."

From William Shirer, "[American Sees the War from Berlin](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/78816782?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *[Perth, Western Australia] Daily News* (March 15, 1941):

> Most of the British attacks have been made on the factories that skirt the city. The British, so far as I know, have never made a single **'terror' attack** on the residential or business quarters of any German city.
>
> More important even than the damage done by the R.A.F. to plants has been the considerable number of working hours lost during the air raids and also the decreased efficiency of the workers due to loss of sleep.

From "[Patrol Clashes in Burma](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/48751832?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *[Adelaide, South Australia] Advertiser* (April 8, 1942):

> He [a reporter for the *Daily Express*] adds that it now has been revealed that the Japanese made a very heavy attack on Mandalay last Saturday. Between 2,000 and 3,000 persons are reported to have been killed, several thousand wounded and over half the business section destroyed. The raid clearly was a **terror attack** preceding a land thrust.

From "[German Claims](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/42343537?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *Cairns [Queensland] Post* (May 11, 1942):

> A Berlin communique says that as a reprisal for R.A.F. attacks against German towns and rural districts, the Luftwaffe last night low-level attacked Norwich.
>
> The R.A.F. last night dropped high explosives and incendiaries on Rostock and the bathing resort of Warnemunde. The R.A.F. last 18 bombers in this new **terror attack** against civilians.

This appears to be the first instance of a newspaper describing its own military's tactical incursion as a "terror attack." Also, from "[Canterbury Attacked: German Reprisal Raid](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/47334653?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *[Perth, Western Australia] West Australian* (June 2, 1942):

> The Berlin communique states: "Strong Luftwaffe formations, as a reprisal for the RAF **terror attack** on the centre of the city of Cologne, attacked the bishopric seat of Canterbury with thousands of high ex plosive and fire bombs which caused large fires."

Interestingly, while Britain and Germany used different wording to describe RAF tactics, Australian newspapers didn't seem overly concerned with the bad PR aspects of using the wording "terror attack." An article titled "[100th Raid on Bremen: R.A.F. Also Over France and Holland](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/61764694?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)," in the *Townsville [Queensland] Daily Bulletin* (September 16, 1942) conveniently prints dispatches from London and Berlin regarding a bombing raid on Bremen:

> LONDON, September 14.—Last night's raid was Bremen's 100th.
>
> The Air Ministry reports that, in addition to night raids, single bombers attacked other targets in Northern Germany at dawn to-day. Fighter Command planes last night carried out intruder patrols over North France. Nineteen bombers are missing from all of the operations.
>
> The Air Ministry states Fighter Command intruder pilots were also over Holland last night.
>
> BERLIN September 14.— R.A.F. formations carried out a **terror attack** last night, particularly against Bremen. There were civilian casualties and fires in residential districts and damage to buildings, including several churches, hospitals and cultural monuments.

As the war continued, the official German news agency repeatedly characterized allied bombing attacks on German cities as "terror attacks"—which they surely were in many cases. Dozens of news articles in the National Library of Australia's Trove newspaper database quote the agency's characterization without disputing it, emphasizing instead that the characterization usually amounted to conceding that a particular attack had been quite effective.

Late in the war, "terror attack" reappears in connection with irregular, nonstate tactics. A headline in the *[Adelaide, South Australia] Mail* titled "[Terror Attack by Native Axemen](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/55862203?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)" reports on an attack by "An outlaw tribe that has long terrorised New Britain natives." A similar headline in the *[Brisbane, Queensland] Courier-Mail* (April 3, 1950) reports "[17 Injured in Terror Attack](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/49735301?searchTerm=%22terror+attack%22)" in connection with a hand-grenade attack by terrorists in Kuala Lumpur, Malaya, that targeted Malay soldiers at an amusement park, but fell short and injured civilians instead.

The phrase "terror attack" appears in body copy in "[Assassins Face Quick Justice](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth284069/m1/1/zoom/?q=%22terror%20attack%22&resolution=4&lat=3482.5&lon=4235.5)," in the *Sweetwater [Texas] Reporter* (March 3, 1954):

> Th government pressed for speedy grand jury action against 4 Puerto Rican assassins Wednesday as the Justice Department considered slapping criminal charges on the leaders who may have spawned the **terror attack** in Congress Monday.
>
> Informed sources revealed that department experts believe there is a chance the government can prosecute Puerto Rican Nationalist party chiefs under the Smith act which sent U. S. Communist leaders to jail.

(As a side note, it is interesting that the headline refers to the Puerto Rican attackers as "assassins" even though no one was in fact assassinated.)

An orchestrated attack on private citizens is the subject of "[Bombing Case Facts Revealed](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=MT19581014.2.9&txq=%2522terror+attack%2522)" in the *Madera [California] Tribune* (October 14, 1958):

> Authorities appeared to be on the verge of cracking wide open a **terror attack** on Jewish synagogues and temples in the South.
>
> Local authorities, working hand in hand with the FBI. were confident they were on the right track. They have been working around the clock on the case since dynamite ripped a huge hole in the fashionable temple [in Atlanta, Georgia] early Sunday, causing $200,000 damage.

The phrase "terror attack" appears 34 times during the 1960s and 1970s, always in the context of attacks by guerillas or domestic revolutionaries on regular military personnel or private citizens. The notion of direct, state-authored terror attacks as a military tactic is nowhere to be found. In "[Mubarak Blamed for Terrorism](https://newspapers.library.in.gov/cgi-bin/indiana?a=d&d=JPOST19851016-01.1.10&txq=%22terror+attack%22)" in the *[Indianapolis, Indiana] Jewish Post* (October 6, 1985), following an attack in which seven Israeli tourists were killed in the Sinai Peninsula, the president of Herut Zionists of America "demanded that the Egyptian government immediately provide a 'full and comprehensive accounting of both its direct and indirect involvement in this terror attack.'" But even if the Herut president's suspicions were justified—and the article didn't identify any supporting evidence—this instance is a far cry from an official policy of Second World War–style military attacks to engender civilian terror.

---

***'Terrorist attack' in the news***

Elephind search results yield matches for "terrorist attack" going back to 1905. From "[Another Russian Official Gone](http://idnc.library.illinois.edu/cgi-bin/illinois?a=d&d=TQU19050530.1.3&txq=%22terrorist+attack%22)," in the *[La Harpe, Illinois] Quill* (May 30, 1905):

> Prince Nakachidza, governor of Baku, Caucasia, was killed by a bomb and a lieutenant and a bystander also were victims. The chief of police of Siedlie was wounded by another **terrorist attack**.

From "[Hid Bomb in Her Hair: Arrest of Woman Revolutionist at Moscow](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1906-03-06/ed-1/seq-17/#words=%22terrorist+attack%22)," in the *[Washington D.C.] Evening Star* (March 6, 1906):

> A boldly planned attempt on the life of Vice Admiral Doubasoff, governor general of Moscow and member of the council of the empire, was frustrated in that city yesterday. As in the case of Vice Admiral Chouknin, who, on February 9 of this year, was the object of a **terrorist attack**, the would-be assassin was a woman, and her method was practically the same as that of the woman who attempted the life of Chouknin.

From "[Affairs in Russia: Personal Appeal by the Czar](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/124380181?searchTerm=%22terrorist+attack%22)," in the *[Ipswich] Queensland Times* (August 30, 1906):

> It is semi-officially announced at St. Petersburg [following the assassination of General Minn] that the Government cannot yield to the **terrorist attack**, and will firmly adhere to its announced policy. Arrests on a huge scale continue to be made at St. Petersburg.

From "[Robbery of Treasure: Additional Particulars](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/87335656?searchTerm=%22terrorist+attack%22)," in the *Colac [Victoria] Herald* (October 31, 1906):

> Additional particulars are to hand regarding the **Terrorist attack** on Saturday [in St. Petersburg, in which a Treasury train was robbed of £36,000 by a group of twenty "terrorists"]. It appears that the authorities were fully warned that an attempt would he made to rob the Treasury carriage, but regarded the escort of eight gendarmes as sufficient to repel and overpower any movement in that direction. The attack was made about noon to-day, in the midst of city activity.

From "[**Terrorist Attack**](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045366/1906-11-19/ed-1/seq-3/#words=%22terrorist+attack%22)," in the *Minneapolis [Minnesota] Journal* (November 19, 1906):

> Warsaw, Russian Poland, Nov. 19.—A daring **terrorist attack** was made in the street this morning on a collector of the government alcohol stores, who was escorted by two soldiers. The terrorists killed on soldier, wounded the collector and seized a bag containing $1,000. The remaining soldier fired wildly, killed one passerby and wounded another, whereupon the terrorists dropped their booty and escaped.

And from "[Shot Down by Cossacks: Innocent Mill hands Slain in Retaliation for **Terrorist Attack**](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn84022835/1907-05-24/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22terrorist+attack%22)" in the *Red Cloud [Nebraska] Chief* (May 24, 1907):

> Lodz, Russian Poland. May 18.—Sixty-elght officials and workmen of Kuttner's spinning mills were shot down by a patrol of Cossacks, because a band of terrorists attacked a mail wagon in the neighborhood, killing a Cossack and two postoffice officials.
>
> While the wagon was passing through Lonkowa street the terrorists suddenly appeared from a side street, opened fire on the Cossack escort, and seized $1,000 from the wagon and escaped.
>
> A moment later a patrol of Cossacks arrived on the scene and, infuriated by the fate of their comrades, rushed into the Kuttner factory, which was near the spot where the robbery occurred, and began firing indiscriminately, killing twenty-one and wounding forty-seven persons.

It is difficult not to notice the Russian connection in these articles. In fact the first newspaper use of "terrorist attack" in a context that doesn't involve Russian (or Polish) anarchists, revolutionaries, or brigands involves a bomb plot in the United States, reported in "[London Press Absolves Labor from Any Part in Bomb Plot Here](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83030193/1919-06-04/ed-1/seq-2/#words=%22terrorist+attack%22)," in the *[New York] Evening World* (June 4, 1919):

> London newspapers to-day gave considerable prominence to the latest bomb plot in the United States. They pointed out that it was a **terrorist attack** against the Federal authority, and in no way connected with the labor movement.

This was the heyday of the "red terror" scare in the United States, when fears of imported Bolshevism, with its evocation of alleys and tenements filled with wild-eyed mad bombers, led to an upsurge in the peculiar American form of xenophobia that periodically grips that nation of immigrants.

---

***Conclusions: 'terror attack' versus 'terrorist attack'***

The term "terrorist attack" seems to be the older formulation of the two "Terrorist attack" emerged with a bang in 1906, in a series of newspaper accounts of bomb-throwing assassins and would-be assassins striking targets in Russia—mainly officials in the czar's government or military apparatus. Some of the attacks sound a lot like high-end robberies, but the newspaper accounts show no hesitation in calling them "terrorist attacks."

In fact, the earliest news article I could find in which a "terrorist attack" is reported as targeting civilians rather than government or military personnel is "[Police Net Tightens on Indian Terrorists: Europeans on Guard](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/29883154?searchTerm=%22Police+Net+Tightens+on+Indian+Terrorists%22)" in the *[Adelaide, South Australia] Advertiser* (December 29, 1931)—and the distinction between civilians and government functionaries of an occupying power is somewhat strained in this case because the terrorists are Bengali revolutionaries targeting European residents of India.

The term "terror attack" came into its own during the Second World War, when bombing raids that inadvertently or intentionally struck civilian areas were characterized by both sides as "terror attacks"—that is, as attacks by a country's military forces that had the effect of physically and psychologically damaging noncombatant populations within the enemy nation. This understanding of "terror attack" vanished rather quickly after 1945, however, and today I find little or no distinction in how "terror attack" and "terrorist attack" are used.

Nor do most writers make any distinction between civilian targets and what might be called legitimate government or military targets in applying either term. Today, the defining feature of a terrorist (or terror) attack is not the target, but the identity of the attackers and the method by which the attack occurs: it is irregular or asymmetric and small-scale—at least in terms of the number of participating combatants—and typically it involves elements of guerilla warfare such as combatants who blend into the surrounding civilian population.

This is a very broad definition, as you can see when you stop to consider that the rescue of Princess Leia in the original *Star Wars* movie qualifies in every respect as a terrorist attack.

Answer (score 0):

There is no essentially big difference between the two.  A terror attack emphasis the fact that it is done to strike fear or terror as a result of ideology whereas terrorist attack emphasizes that the attack was done by people intending to strike fear or terror as a result of their ideology.

I don't like the term "terror attack" or "terrorist attack" because any violent crime results in fear or terror.  These terms express the result of some act, not their motivation.  Why should attacking someone for so-called religious motivations be called terrorism when attacking someone violently for money isn't?  Both cause fear, but I digress...

Comment: I'm not sure I share your view. When the police or other authorities state, for example, that a particular crime, is not thought to be "terrorist related" they are effectively saying that it is not suspected as having been carried out by an organisation for ideological reasons.  It is a way of categorising incidents according to the believed motivation of the perpetrator(s).

Comment: @WS2 thanks for sharing your viewpoint. I know that that is a way of sharing the difference in type of crime, I just don't think that this terminology is effective way of expressing that.  When I think of terror, I think of fear, not the motivation behind someone when giving me fear.  I guess I also object to how it is used to mean "something" worse than other crimes for victims who have all suffered trauma.

Comment: I agree with you about "terror", as in "terror attack" etc. To the extent it is used I don't think it conveys the clear meaning that "terrorist incident" does.  The latter, however, is now the accepted nomenclature in police as well as general public circles to mean a politically or religiously-motivated attack.